# Add shadow behind the image view in android

Tags: android

Add shadow  behind the image view in android
here is a example image with default shadow in android:
[image]

and xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.home.fmat.MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/on"
    android:src="@drawable/Google_Duo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show the xml layout

Comment: You could set null background, but I think `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` is more correct

Comment: that question did not ask about chaning background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that background is default ImageButton background.
change `ImageButton` with `ImageView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.home.fmat.MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/on"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
    android:src="@drawable/Google_Duo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or if you don't want click effect disappear, set ImageButton background with custom background, for example by using statelistdrawable, for example in your drawables, you can define `bg_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/red" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>    
</selector>
```

Comment: how to use statelistdrawable

Comment: I update my answer, I hope it can help you

Comment: i am getting error "Element selector must be declared" when creates the bg_button.xml

Comment: please make sure you put `bg_button.xml` inside folder `drawable` not in `layout` folder

Comment: oh sorry man i put it in the values.

Comment: then what is selectableItemBackground

Comment: `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, 
that android theme based drawable background. it depend on android version

Comment: ok thank you hakim.